# Spark Structured Streaming Visualization

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, visualization, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to visualize streaming queries in structured streaming. 
How could I do that?
Should I use dashboards or is there any other tool?

I cannot find anything similar on the Web.

```
DF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)\
    .option("subscribe", topics)\
    .load()\
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

...
 query1 = prediction.writeStream.outputMode("update").format('console').start()
 query1.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - queryName the clue:

Scala

```
// Have all the aggregates in an in-memory table
val aggDF
 .writeStream
 .queryName("aggregates")    // this query name will be the table name
 .outputMode("complete")
 .format("memory")
 .start()

spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show()
```

pyspark

```
# Have all the aggregates in an in-memory table. The query name will be the table name
aggDF \
  .writeStream \
  .queryName("aggregates") \
  .outputMode("complete") \
  .format("memory") \
  .start()

spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show()   # interactively query in-memory table
```

Notebooks from DataBricks have a `display` function.